# Convert Eigen Affine3d to Affine2d

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I have an [affine transform](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TutorialGeometry.html#TutorialGeoTransform) in 3D and I wish to discard any z-axis information from. Is there a convenient way to convert from an `Affine3d` to and `Affine2d`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following:

```
Affine2d S2d = Translation2d(S3d.translation().topRows<2>()) *
               S3d.linear().topLeftCorner<2,2>();
```

Demo:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    using namespace Eigen;
    using namespace std;

    Vector3d p3d(1.,2.,3.);
    cout << p3d << endl << endl;
    Affine3d S3d = Translation3d(2.,2.,2.)*Scaling(3.,2.,5.);
    Vector3d scalled = S3d*p3d;
    cout << S3d.matrix() << endl << endl;
    cout << scalled << endl << endl;

    cout << string(16,'_') << endl;

    Vector2d p2d = p3d.topRows<2>();
    cout << p2d << endl << endl;
    Affine2d S2d = Translation2d(S3d.translation().topRows<2>()) *
                   S3d.linear().topLeftCorner<2,2>();
    Vector2d scalled2d = S2d*p2d;
    cout << S2d.matrix() << endl << endl;
    cout << scalled2d << endl << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3

3 0 0 2
0 2 0 2
0 0 5 2
0 0 0 1

5
6
17

________________
1
2

3 0 2
0 2 2
0 0 1

5
6
```

Comment: @DrewNoakes You are welcome! However, maybe there is more convenient way to do this.

Comment: `S3d` is a 4x4 matrix while `p3d` is vector or say 3x1 matrix then how that matrix multiplication `S3d*p3d` is possible? Does *Eigen* converts the vector `p3d` to homogeneous coordinates i.e. appends 1 at the bottom and makes it 4x1 matrix before multiplication and converts it back to Cartesian coordinates afterward?

Comment: @Milan `S3d` is not just a regular 4x4 matrix, it is an object of special type: `typedef Transform< double, 3, Affine > Affine3d;`
http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-3.2/classEigen_1_1Transform.html