# Displaying an affine transformation in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen, cout, eigen3

I am trying to do something as simple as:

```
std::cout << e << std::endl;
```

where `e` is of type `Eigen::Affine3d`. However, I am getting unhelpful error messages like:

```
cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}'   
lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'
```

The reason for which is helpfully explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24609915/stdvector-cannot-bind-stdostream-aka-stdbasic-ostreamchar-lvalue-t), but where the answer does not apply.

The [official documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialGeometry.html) is curt, implying only that Affine3d and Affine3f objects are matrices. Eigen matrices and vectors can be printed by `std::cout` without issue though. So what is the problem?

Comment: Please include entire error message

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Annoyingly, the `<<` operator is not defined for `Affine` objects. You have to call the `matrix()` function to get the printable representation:

`std::cout << e.matrix() << std::endl;`

If you're not a fan of homogenous matrices:

```
Eigen::Matrix3d m = e.rotation();
Eigen::Vector3d v = e.translation();
std::cout << "Rotation: " << std::endl << m << std::endl;
std::cout << "Translation: " << std::endl << v << std::endl;
```

Hopefully someone can save a few minutes of annoyance.

PS:[Another lonely SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16169811/convert-eigen-affine3d-to-affine2d) mentioned this solution in passing.

Answer (score 4):

To be honest, I would prefer to overload the stream operator. This makes the repeated use more convinient. This you can do like this

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Eigen::Affine3d& affine)
{
    stream << "Rotation: " << std::endl << affine.rotation() << std::endl;
    stream << "Translation: " << std::endl <<  affine.translation() << std::endl;

    return stream;
}

int main()
{

    Eigen::Affine3d l;

    std::cout << l << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Be aware that l is uninitialized**

Comment: This is the neater way that should be in Eigen out of the box in my opinion.